# Enable download in inAppBrowser - Phonegap / Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, webview, inappbrowser

I'm using cordova 3.5-0.26 & inAppBrowser 0.5.0

Now I'm loading an external page in inAppBrowser. There is a download button. When I press the download it doesn't do anything. I thing download is off in inAppBrowser. So as in the cordova view.

Then I tried to active the download manager using following code (for Android)

```
appView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                            long contentLength) {
                      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                      i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                      startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
```

This doesn't work for the inAppBrowser either.

1) How can I enable the download in inAppBrowser? 2) Is there any way to catch the download with default download manager? 3) If possible please mention solution for both ios and android. if not android will do for now. Please help...

Comment: You will need to open the stock browser if you want to use Android's download manager. Unless you are ready to tweak Cordova's Java file to catch any downloadable files and execute it via AsyncTask. More reading here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12078937/541591

Comment: If no other way shows up, I'm ready to tweak the java files. I'll tweak the inAppBrowser java file to force it to download. Though I'm expecting a better solution for both iOS & android. I don't know objective C. @JamesWong

Comment: And I've no problem of using built-in browser's download manager.

Comment: Alternatively you can use Cordova's File API to download the file, your code will work cross platform then.

Comment: nope. That's not an option. External link is a third party website. I have no control over it. So won't have the download url. @JamesWong

Answer (score -1, accepted):

InAppBrowser doesn't allow download. You will need to modify plugin to allow it for downloading.

For android, inside `platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\inappbrowser`

method name `private void navigate(String url) {`

include

```
this.inAppWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                            long contentLength) {
                      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                      i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                      cordova.getActivity().startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
```

before this line `this.inAppWebView.requestFocus();`

again same code in the method `public void run() {`

after this segment

```
if (clearAllCache) {
                CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
            } else if (clearSessionCache) {
                CookieManager.getInstance().removeSessionCookie();
            }

            inAppWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

in your .java file inside onCreate

```
appView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                            long contentLength) {
                      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                      i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                      startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
```

Don't know about iOS

Comment: I tried it and got this error, can you please help me?  this.inAppWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                    ^
  symbol: variable inAppWebView

Comment: It not working.. its not accepted answer.. I have tried same code.. Its never executed..

Comment: Caution: don't waste time using this solution; it just doesn't work at all.