# How to download .pkpass using Cordova Inappbrowser

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser, wallet

I'm using Cordova 6.0.0 and Inappbrowser to create an Android App to browse my mobile site. My mobile site has a button to add coupon (just only a link href to a .pkpass file) into App Wallet.

I have tried it with Google Chrome and it's works but not with Inappbrowser. I think the problem might be occur from Inappbrowser is unable to download a file.

So I have searched for a solution how to download file using Cordova Inappbrowser and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278373/enable-download-in-inappbrowser-phonegap-cordova), discussion about how to make Cordova Inappbrowser downloadable.

Unfortunately, I can't get pass the last step for adding the snippet into .java file (MainActivity.java). The error is "\main\MainActivity.java:34: error: cannot find symbol".

Any suggestion or workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, did u get it working? Im facing same problem.. Can you please help me?