# InAppBrowser won't allow to download

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, inappbrowser

I am using InappBrowser plugin to open the following URL in ionic2
http://pushtimarg.net/dassera-kirtan-2/

But If you open the same URL in the browser, you will able to download "Tracks" listing in it. But same is not possible in InAppBrowser.

My code is as below:

```
let browser = this.iab.create(link, '_self', {location: 'no'});
browser.show();
```

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278373/enable-download-in-inappbrowser-phonegap-cordova

Comment: @sunielkalwani, Thanks but that link is the solution for Android. But I need ios solution also.

Comment: i don't think it is possible for ios till now . may be i am wrong